# Open php outside of webroot

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a stand alone web form to insert data into MySQL. I don't want it to be accessible to my web users. How do I get it to open up in my browser. It currently resides in my home folder. file:///home/user/file.php .

Comment: Why not just add another security level? I assume you are using sessions, check if the user loged in is you, if not bounce them out

Comment: @Ryan B I'd like this to run as a stand alone application, through the browser.  Was hoping to write it in php as to avoid learning a new language. Everything is running local now, so I don't have to worry about security.

Comment: Sessions is part of PHP, so no new language... maybe just a new part of PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php or http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php. The Tizag is a lot easier to digest

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a local LAMP, that is installing Apache and PHP (I assume MySQL is already installed)

Comment: I have LAMP. I can load php files that are in web root. I'd like to do it for files outside of it.

Comment: Are you using Windows, Linux or OSX?

Comment: Then you can create a symlink in your webroot to another folder outside Apache root dir

Comment: Interesting. Then just set the file permissions on the sum link? For example, if I wanted a SYM link to /home/user, am I exposing the directory to any web users